# Bug with keyboard after reinstall 'ubuntu-desktop'?

Tags: ubuntu, layout, keyboard, ubuntu-14.04

I apologize in advance for my English

After reinstall 'ubuntu-desktop' (before can't login, show 'failed to start session) my keyboard settings is broken.
Auto-switch layout keyboard don't work.

When I change window, language switch to default (i. e. eng). Now this 'feature' is not work. This feature really necessary to me.
Keyboard setting: Allow different sources for each window -> Now window use the default

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can have a try changing the shortcuts for changing input sources, which can be done by go to setting->keyboard->shortcuts->typing.

if it doesn't work. 
Download it from [official website](http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.04/), normally, keyboard doesn't need extra drivers.